# Linux Mint 19 through WDS PXE does not boot

Tags: mount, pxe-boot, wds, tmp, linuxmint

I find myself stuck trying to make linux mint 19 available from my wds.

I can boot windows, ubuntu, centos, debian, kali linux AND linux mint 18 with minimal problems but linux mint 19 just won't boot.

**Curent menu file :**

```
DEFAULT      vesamenu.c32
PROMPT       0

MENU TITLE PXE Boot Menu
MENU INCLUDE pxelinux.cfg/graphics.conf

## Local Boot ##

LABEL local
menu label ^Boot Normally
localboot -1
Type 0x80

## Windows ##

LABEL wds
menu label Install Windows
KERNEL pxeboot.0

## Linux ##

LABEL LinuxMint18Cinnamon
MENU LABEL ^LIVE Linux Mint 18 Cinnamon
KERNEL /ISO/Mint18Cinnamon/casper/vmlinuz
APPEND boot=casper netboot=nfs nfsroot=192.168.1.6:/ISO/Mint18Cinnamon initrd=/ISO/Mint18Cinnamon/casper/initrd.lz

label Centos7
menu label ^Install Centos 7
KERNEL /Linux/Centos7/vmlinuz
APPEND initrd=/Linux/Centos7/initrd.img repo=nfs:192.168.1.6:/ISO/CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-1810.iso 

label Debian9.8
menu label ^Install Debian 9.8
kernel /Linux/Debian9.8/linux
append initrd=/Linux/Debian9.8/initrd.gz
  
label Ubuntu19.04
menu label ^Install Ubuntu 19.04
kernel /Linux/Ubuntu19.04/linux
append initrd=/Linux/Ubuntu19.04/initrd.gz

LABEL Kali Linux 2019
MENU LABEL ^Kali 2019
kernel /ISO/Kali2019/live/vmlinuz
append vga=normal boot=live netboot=nfs nfsroot=192.168.1.6:/ISO/Kali2019 initrd=/ISO/Kali2019/live/initrd.img

## TESTING ##

LABEL LinuxMint19Cinnamon
MENU LABEL ^Install Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon
KERNEL /ISO/Mint19Cinnamon/casper/vmlinuz
APPEND boot=casper netboot=nfs nfsroot=192.168.1.6:/ISO/Mint19Cinnamon initrd=/ISO/Mint19Cinnamon/casper/initrd.lz
```

**Errors**

- `Failed to start Set console font and keymap error`

  `systemctl status console-setup.service` gives the same error, with an additionnal `/bin/setupcon: 903: /bin/setupcon: cannot open /tmp/tempkbd.axcw04: No sush file`. Restarting `console-setup.service` makes it work, but I am still stuck with no live mint.
- `Failed to mount /tmp`

  `systemctl status tmp.mount` says `Mount process finished, but there is no mount.` and `Failed with result "protocol"`. Restarting `tmp.mount` does not change anything.

I've also tried configuring it the same way as the other distros, but I never go as far as Linux Mint 18's, so I'm not going to explain every last error they made.

I did try adding `rw` at the end of the `APPEND`, but it did not change anything. Also added `root=/dev/nfs` and a combination of the two, but still the same errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Pat I figured out that I only need to add `toram` to the `APPEND` for it to work.

**The working config :**

```
LABEL LinuxMint19Cinnamon
MENU LABEL ^Install Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon
KERNEL /ISO/Mint19Cinnamon/casper/vmlinuz
APPEND toram boot=casper netboot=nfs nfsroot=192.168.1.6:/ISO/Mint19Cinnamon initrd=/ISO/Mint19Cinnamon/casper/initrd.lz
```

Answer (score 1):

See [here](https://www.vercot.com/~serva/an/NonWindowsPXE3.html) how Serva PXE boots Mint 19. In that case CIFS is used instead of NFS but you can easily change the afected variables.

```
[PXESERVA_MENU_ENTRY]
asset    = Mint 19 Live
platform = 64bit

kernel_bios    = /NWA_PXE/$HEAD_DIR$/casper/vmlinuz
append_bios    = showmounts toram root=/dev/cifs initrd=/NWA_PXE/$HEAD_DIR$/casper/initrd.lz,/NWA_PXE/$HEAD_DIR$/casper/INITRD_N11.2.3.GZ boot=casper netboot=cifs nfsroot=//$IP_BSRV$/NWA_PXE_SHARE/$HEAD_DIR$ NFSOPTS=-ouser=serva,pass=avres,sec=ntlm,vers=1.0,ro ip=dhcp ro ipv6.disable=1
ipappend_bios  = 2

kernel_efi64   = /NWA_PXE/$HEAD_DIR$/casper/vmlinuz
append_efi64   = showmounts toram root=/dev/cifs initrd=/NWA_PXE/$HEAD_DIR$/casper/initrd.lz,/NWA_PXE/$HEAD_DIR$/casper/INITRD_N11.2.3.GZ boot=casper netboot=cifs nfsroot=//$IP_BSRV$/NWA_PXE_SHARE/$HEAD_DIR$ NFSOPTS=-ouser=serva,pass=avres,sec=ntlm,vers=1.0,ro ip=dhcp ro ipv6.disable=1
ipappend_efi64 = 2
```

See how Serva uses an additional **INITRD_N11.2.3.GZ** providing needed scripts and/or missing kernel modules fpr PXE being able to work